# I need to change the permission of a particular folder in windows

Tags: windows

The folder reverts to read-only every time i change the permission.

What i have tried already :
1.Changing the owner of the folder to current user with full control.
2.Changing the owner of the folder to everyone with full control.
3.Unchecking the read-only checkbox and apply,Ok.
4.From command line : using attrib command
5.Changing the owner and permission of the drive in which the folder is.

Note : When creating a new folder then also the folder is read-only with same above problems.

Please help me , i ve been stuck in this for days and unable to resolve.

This error throws up when trying to update the existing XML file

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvyDN.png)

Comment: No it doesn't _revert to read only_. It is a tristate checkbox (Checked, Unchecked, and Indeterminate) and it ALWAYS shows indeterminate for folders. Read Only doesn't mean much on a folder, for MSDos compat reasons CMD.exe won't let you delete. But Explorer will.

Comment: What folder? What is inside the folder?